# What would make old fashioned fudge tough?

Tags: fudge

I've been making old fashioned fudge for years with great success. But today my fudge came out tough. It's not the normal I overbeat it and its grainy and a little hard. It's like trying to eat plastic. I have no idea what I've done wrong.

I made two batches and they both came out this way, I did slightly overbeat them but I've never seen it be completely inedible because of it... you legitimately can't eat the fudge it is so chewy.

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: You may have cooked it too long... do you do the soft ball stage test when you make fudge?

Comment: I use a candy thermometer. I pulled the second batch off about 8°F early but it can out worse. I'll try another batch next week and use the soft ball test instead.

Comment: Before your next batch, test your candy thermometer and make sure it's still reading correctly. It may be "off" a bit.